# SQL Server 2008 database copy - file permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-vista, 64-bit, administration

For SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition on Vista 64 bit:

I tried copying a database using a Vista admin account using the attach/detach method and it failed due to a file permission error so I gave the user that sql services are running as write and modify to the directory.  The copy didn't work.  I then gave it full control.  The copy worked.

Does that make sense?

If I revoke full control from the user, will that cause problems?

The weird thing is that in an existing working database with files in a different directory, there are no special permissions on the directory and files for the database, so why does a copy require full control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you detach a DB, the MDF/LDF files may be set with more restricted perms than you expect, like exclusive to the principal that did the detach - maybe the SQL Server service account or the domain account of the user that performed the detach. I have in the past had to manually add back permissions on the files' Properties > Security tab for other users, or else the files act as if they are locked. See also http://www.onupdatecascade.com/2009/07/sql-server-locks-mdf-and-ldf-files-upon.html

also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189128.aspx

( thanks [GrumpyOldDBA](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/grumpyolddba/archive/2010/02/01/detach-a-database-and-take-out-a-cluster.aspx) )

Answer (score 0):

If the server and/or data you are working on does not require those restrictive permissions to be set, you can set a startup flag in SQL Server that will override this function.  I understand what Microsoft is going for with this - they assume if you detach a DB they don't want just anyone to walk away with the file; however, I think keeping a good hacker from doing that is easier said than done, and encrypting the DB is the best method for safeguarding data.

Anyway, there is a "Trace Flag 1802" which is oddly named, since it's nothing to do with tracing. You'll want to add it to your SQL startup in SQL Configuration Manager if you want to keep this behavior.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/922804

I myself had the same issue and found the answer in StackExchange:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77683/11001